# Can (should) robolectric be used to test Intent Filter

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have an app that launches a specific activity if a certain URL with a custom scheme is used.  For example if "myscheme://www.myapp.com/mypath" is used in a webview, my app is launched.  To do this, I configure intent filters in the manifest as so:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.View" />
    <data android:scheme="myscheme" android:host="www.myapp.com" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

I'd like to verify that this works and continues to work by writing a unit test.

```
@Test   
public void testIntentHandling()
{
    Activity launcherActivity = new Activity();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("myscheme://www.myapp.com/mypath"));
    launcherActivity.startActivity(intent);

    ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Robolectric.shadowOf(launcherActivity);
    Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();
    ShadowIntent shadowIntent = Robolectric.shadowOf(startedIntent);
    assertNotNull(shadowIntent);
    System.out.println(shadowIntent.getAction());
    System.out.println(shadowIntent.getData().toString());
    System.out.println(shadowIntent.getComponent().toShortString());

    assertEquals("com.mycompany", shadowIntent.getComponent().getPackageName());
}
```

However, this does not work.  What I get is "shadowIntent.getComponent()" returns null, when it should return the component that specifies my application and activity.  Since most of this work is done by the Android system, not my app, is it fair to assume that Robolectric does not mimic this, and so can not be used to test this feature?  Am I right to assume I can/should unit test weather my manifest is setup correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would not test it in this way. You're basically testing part of Android.

I would have one test that is you `AndroidManifest.xml` declaration is correct. And I would have one/two test that are checking that your activity is handling intent with data correctly